# pandas groupby create a new dataframe with label from apply operation

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to create a new dataframe with labeled column('off') after applying my function.

```
df_onoff = df_sample.groupby('id')['digits'].apply(lambda nums: "%d" % ', '.join(format(n%2**60,'060b') for n in nums).count('01'))
```

Here's the output now:

```
id
4013    466
4014    592
4015    566
4016    466
```

And I want the output to be:

```
id      off
4013    466
4014    592
4015    566
4016    466
```

Any idea? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.reset_index.html) because output is `Series`:

```
df_onoff = df_sample.groupby('id')['digits']
                    .apply(lambda nums: "%d" % ', '.join(format(n%2**60,'060b') for n in nums).count('01'))
                    .reset_index()
```

If possible, add parameter name:

```
.reset_index(name='off')
```

Or rename column:

```
.reset_index().rename(columns={'digits':'off'})
```

Comment: Super, nice weekend!

Comment: I'd like to calculate mean after counting '01''s. What's the way to do it? I tried calling mean() but it throws an error `df_sample.groupby('id')['digits']
                    .apply(lambda nums: "%d" % ', '.join(format(n%2**60,'060b') for n in nums).count('01')).mean().
                    .reset_index()`

Comment: Not sure if understand your question - if have data `df_sample = pd.DataFrame({'digits':[4,2,6,0,8,1],
                          'id':list('aaabbb')})` after apply function get `a ->3, b ->2`. For each group count `01`. So then output is scalar `(3+2)/2=2.5` ? Or need something else? What is desired output?

Comment: What I want is the sum of '01' digits divided by # of time unique time readings. There's one more column which records time in 5 minute interval per every 'digit' column.

Comment: I think the best is create new question with sample data, desired output and your code as many comments. I think you get some nice answer(s). Good luck!